# Web Scraping Python BeautifulSoup get elements for each webpage in website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am in my infancy of python coding. What I am trying to do is build a web scraper which gets all the links from a website and then returns the elements form each site. The code I started with is from https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-all-website-links-python
this works really nicely to get all the links from a website.
As I am only interested in the internal links I have added some extra code to try and get the elements (tile, h1, some other bits which I haven't added yet) to the code. The issue I am running into is I think the href returns an email, then the code tries and extracts the elements from this so obviously this bugs out. I have tried to avoid it picking the email (which i also thought would be in the def_valid function) but i am obviously missing something. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import re
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import colorama

GREEN = colorama.Fore.GREEN
GRAY = colorama.Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX
RESET = colorama.Fore.RESET
YELLOW = colorama.Fore.YELLOW

internal_urls = set()
external_urls = set()
title_urls = set()

def is_valid(url):
    """
    Checks whether `url` is a valid URL.
    """
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)


def get_all_website_links(url):
    """
    Returns all URLs that is found on `url` in which it belongs to the same website
    """
    # all URLs of `url`
    urls = set()
    # domain name of the URL without the protocol
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    # is_internal_link == True:

    title_check = soup.find_all('title')
    if title_check != " " or title_check != None:
        get_title(url)
        get_heading_tags(url)
    for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
       # is_internal_link = False
        href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href == "" or href is None:
            # href empty tag
            continue
        # join the URL if it's relative (not absolute link)
        href = urljoin(url, href)
        parsed_href = urlparse(href)
        # remove URL GET parameters, URL fragments, etc.
        href = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
        if not is_valid(href):
            # not a valid URL
            continue
        if href in internal_urls:
            # already in the set
            continue
        if domain_name not in href:
            # external link
            if href not in external_urls:
                #print(f"{GRAY}[!] External link: {href}{RESET}")
                external_urls.add(href)
            continue
        print(f"{GREEN}[*] Internal link: {href}{RESET}")
        if re.search('@',href) == True:
            continue

        urls.add(href)
        internal_urls.add(href)

    return urls


# number of urls visited so far will be stored here
total_urls_visited = 0

def get_title(url):   # domain name of the URL without the protocol
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
#print("Title of the website is : ")
    for title in soup.find_all('title'):
        if title == "" and title == None:
            continue
        title_text = title.get_text()
        title_urls.add(title_text)
        print(title_text)
        print((len(title_text)))
def get_heading_tags(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    heading_tags = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
    i = 0
    for tags in soup.find_all(heading_tags):
        if tags == " " or tags == None:
            continue
        tags_text = tags.get_text()
        letters_in_tags = len(tags_text) - tags_text.count(" ")
        i += 1
        print(f'{tags.name} {i} -> {tags_text} -> Length ->{letters_in_tags} ')


def crawl(url, max_urls=80):
    """
    Crawls a web page and extracts all links.
    You'll find all links in `external_urls` and `internal_urls` global set variables.
    params:
        max_urls (int): number of max urls to crawl, default is 30.
    """

    global total_urls_visited
    total_urls_visited += 1
    print(f"{YELLOW}[*] Crawling: {url}{RESET}")

    links = get_all_website_links(url)

    for link in links:
        if re.search('@',link) != True:
            if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
                break
            crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawl("https://website.com/") #put website here. 
    print("[+] Total Internal links:", len(internal_urls))
    print("[+] Total External links:", len(external_urls))
    print("[+] Total URLs:", len(external_urls) + len(internal_urls))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for link in links:
        if re.search('@',link) != True:
            if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
                break
            crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)
```

You are only checking if `@` is present in the link (and that too not Correct!) to know if it's an email or not. Also note that links can also have `@` in them.

Basically, emails inside `<a>` will be of the form:

```
<a href="mailto:someemail@example.com"></a>
```

So to differentiate emails from links, you can use the below check.

```
for link in links:
    if not link.startswith('mailto:'):
        if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
            break
        crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)
```

This will ignore all the emails and only scrape links.

Comment: Thanks!!! That solved it. Really appreciate the explanation.